# Magento 2 - Adding external link for Font Awesome URL

Tags: magento2, theme, development

Here I am making my own theme and I want to add font-awesome external URL. I have created a file in my custom-theme directory in the path

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

I am following this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

But after clearing the cache, I could not find the **font-awesome link** in the view source.

Please guide me. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" type="text/css" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Then run `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: No. it is not working. Any other solution . @Ronak Rathod

Comment: In browser press ctrl + u and see your css load or not ?

Comment: Yes I did that my css load but font awesome was not loaded.